# SQL Server - Ignore inserts for a particular column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch (in thousands against different tables) of auto generated INSERT statements. I want to ignore update to one particular column in the table.

For e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, aced00057372002d, 'word')
```

I want to ignore any updates to col2. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to code an [INSTEAD OF trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) for each table to handle this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_table1_no_col2 ON table1
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO table1
        (col1, col3)
        SELECT col1, col3
            FROM Inserted
GO
```

Comment: Note of course that this wil work only for all inserts. If you only want this beahvior some of time, that's a whole other issue.